# CSS/HTML: Center text in window without scroll bars

Tags: html, css

I've looked everywhere to center text in a window and I believe I found the best solution (I believe... I'm up for other suggestions).  However, I get these annoying scroll bars on both sides no matter how large or small the window is.

Can you guys take a look at this code/fiddle and let me know why the scroll bars are there and how to remove them?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One' rel='stylesheet'       type='text/css'>
  <style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Asset', cursive;
        font-size: 100px;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    div {
        position:absolute; 
        height:100%; 
        width:100%;
        display: table;
    }

    h1 {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align:center;
    }

  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rYe7V/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rYe7V/1/

Just add to `body`:

```
margin: 0;
```

Comment: I will.  As soon as it allows me to... a few more minutes.

Answer (score 2):

you can remove the scrollbars like this. http://jsfiddle.net/rYe7V/2/

```
body
{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Nicklas beat you to it so I'm afraid he's the winner.... but +1 for a working answer.